# Build fails with java.lang.NullPointerException with Open JDK9

Tags: jmeter, java

I am trying to build Jmeter 4_0 from source with Open JDK9 on Ubuntu 17.10 platform. 
Build is failing with below error:

```
init-version:
     [echo] jmeter.version = 4.0
     [echo] display.version = 4.0.20180223
     [echo] implementation.version = 4.0.20180223

compile-jorphan:
    [javac] Compiling 61 source files to /root/apache-jmeter-4.0/build/jorphan
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.8
    [javac] 1 warning
    [javac] An exception has occurred in the compiler (9-Ubuntu). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
    [javac] java.lang.NullPointerException
    [javac]     at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.JarFileSystem.getVersionMap(JarFileSystem.java:137)
    [javac]     at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.JarFileSystem.createVersionedLinks(JarFileSystem.java:112)
    [javac]     at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.JarFileSystem.<init>(JarFileSystem.java:85)
    [javac]     at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:134)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager$ArchiveContainer.<init>(JavacFileManager.java:517)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.getContainer(JavacFileManager.java:319)
    [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.list(JavacFileManager.java:715)
```

steps followed:

```
installed openjdk-9-jdk 
wget http://redrockdigimark.com/apachemirror//jmeter/source/apache-jmeter-4.0_src.zip 
unzip apache-jmeter-4.0_src.zip 
cd apache-jmeter-4.0 
ant download_jars 
ant
```

Tried with

```
git clone http://git.apache.org/jmeter.git
git checkout v4_0
```

Ref:  http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi

Please let me know if I'm missing anything here.

Comment: I think like exception says, it's a bug in JDK. This might be it: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8193802 (resolved on Jan 31, seems target version is 11, which is not yet released it seems: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/projects/JDK/versions/18723)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per https://stackoverflow.com/users/5318223/kiril-s answer (who should answer instead of commenting :-) to be rewarded) .

This is a JDK bug:

- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8193802

Fixed in JDK11 to be released. Hoping it will be backported .

Comment: The Backports section of JDK-8193802 lists the versions that it has been back-ported to.